# Codename One: Dialog in Lifecycle.java

Tags: codenameone

In Lifecycle.java there is a method:

```
    protected void handleNetworkError(NetworkEvent err) {
        // prevent the event from propagating`
        err.consume();
        if (err.getError() != null) {
            Log.e(err.getError());
        }
        Log.sendLogAsync();
        Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
    }
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent the dialog from showing?
I handle the response to the network call based on the http status (200, 400, 404, etc) - the dialog just adds technical noise that the end user shouldn't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is demo code that you can override and replace with your own custom code. It's useful for debugging but might not be ideal for production.

I leave it in place though and make sure to mark the error as "handled" so it doesn't propagate up the chain. This depends very much on how you handle the response codes.

For the case you describe in the comments you can disable the error code handling by invoking this code in the `init(Object)` callback method:

```
ConnectionRequest.setHandleErrorCodesInGlobalErrorHandler(false);
```

However, a better approach would be to use code like this:

```
request.addResponseCodeListener(ev -> {
      // hanlde error logic
      ev.consume();
});
```

That would stop the propagation of the error handling logic.

Comment: I'm simply preparing a MultipartRequest (setting some header values, and then using request.addData() to add files, and then calling:

            `NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);`

When debugging its this line that causes the dialog to show.

Comment: I added two suggestions to the answer that should cover these uses.